# Not able to download webpack2

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, package.json

I am trying to download webpack2 from npm. Though I am seeing the right version in `package.json` file of my application , but `package.json` file inside webpack folder is showing a different version. Is there any specific reason for it?

I did `npm view webpack versions` to get the version &  `npm install webpack@2.2.0-rc.3 --save-dev` to download webpack. Here is a snapshot

[image: A snapshot of different webpack version]

Comment: Why not simply do `npm install webpack2 --save-dev` that'll automatically update your package.json?

Comment: Isn't local/global different packages? Are you reading `package.json` from your project `node_modules` folder?